# Hiding Column on a List View with Grouping

Tags: 2010, list, javascript, jquery, list-view

I have a list that I need to dynamically hide columns on based on user. Sort of a rudimentary Column Level security type deal. This is being done through Javascript and JQuery to simply not display certain columns when certain logic is met.

Here's the code I currently use to hide a column:

```
var index = $("tr.ms-viewheadertr th:contains('"+ colName +"')").first().index()+1;
$('th:nth-child('+index+'),td:nth-child('+index+')').hide();
```

This works perfectly for List views **without** grouping, but several of the views have multiple groupings and I can't figure out how to make it hide in those sub groups. Anyone know of a work around?

Comment: Did you resolve this? I am encountering the same issue.

Comment: I don't have an answer for this but the code you put up to hide columns in views was really helpful, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem that you have and the solution for your problem is [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pt-BR/69dbe760-e363-48b1-aa16-d7e7c1aa2d72/how-do-i-hide-a-column-when-the-view-is-grouped?forum=sharepointcustomizationprevious)

To it i used the codes below:

```
<script src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function(){$('td:nth-child(Column Number),th:nth-child(Column Number)').hide();});</script>
```

And:

```
<style type="text/css">.ms-vb-title{display:none !important;}</style>
```

Hugs

Comment: Please add a full description of the solution to your answer. If the link you provided breaks in the future, your answer will no longer be helpful. Thanks!